# String split function not working for this string

Tags: java, string, split

Already gone through [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

I have string str = "He|is|a|very|very|good|boy||isn|t|he|"; and want to split on the basis "|". But split function not working...

```
{

 String[] sa = sr.split("|");

 for(String s1 : sa){
            System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Getting output ..

```
H
e
|
i
s
|
a
|
v
e
r
y
|
v
e
r
y
|
g
o
o
d
|
b
o
y
|
|
i
s
n
|
t
|
h
e
|
```

Comment: what is wrong with your output?

Comment: The | character is a special character used for OR expressions, you should escape it using `sr.split("\|");`

Comment: In output still getting pipe"|" symbol, which I wanted to remove

Comment: @SaschaM78 `("\|");` won't work.

Comment: @SaschaM78  this sr.split("\|"); not working

Comment: I didn't close this question as a duplicate for fun you know. You making ill-conceived guesses in the comments won't help. Look at the accepted answer of the duplicate. Jeez.

Comment: @Kayaman Gone through the link of you provided, Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Sorry all for the incorrect escape sequence, had used PHP's escaping rather than Java's. Will take care better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
sr.split("|");
```

won't work unless you escape `|` character using `\` but `\` is also a character so you also need to escape it using another `\`. So instead of `("|");` you need `("\\|");`

Change

```
String[] sa = sr.split("|");
```

to

```
String[] sa = sr.split("\\|");
```

Comment: yes this is working now. thanks for you help. But want to know why it is not working with "|"?